# IPv6: Privacy Extensions sysctl Prefs not respected

Tags: networking, raspbian-buster, dhcp, ipv6

Given the vast address space available for IoT devices using IPv6, I was doing some testing and ran into some funky, inconsistent behaviour regarding address configuration.

In Raspbian Buster, I persistently set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` the preference to disable Privacy Extensions ([RFC 4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941)):

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr=0
```

However, instead of an EUI-64 constructed address, on boot I get an address configured using privacy extensions?  Why are the persistent `sysctl` setting ignored?

Answer (score 2):

The directives in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` override IPv6 Privacy Extensions preferences set persistently in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

### To **DISABLE** Privacy Extensions:

To configure an EUI-64 formatted IPv6 address, in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` set the respective directives as follows:

```
#slaac private
slaac hwaddr
```

### To **ENABLE** Privacy Extensions:

Conversely, invert the preferences to get an interface configured USING IPv6 Privacy Extensions:

```
slaac private
#slaac hwaddr
```

Hope this saves others similar head scratching when configuring host address configuration for IPv6-