# [Solved]IPv6: disabled Privacy Extensions in dhcpcd.conf not respected

Tags: ipv6

I just fired up my Raspi 3B+ again for a little server reachable from the internet via IPv6. I installed the latest Raspberry Pi Os Lite Version using the Raspberry Pi Imager: It installed Raspbian GNU/Linux OS Version 10 (Buster), 32bit.

When I looked at the per DHCP assigned addresses, I noticed, that my Raspi has two IPv6 addresses:

```
pi@XXX-Box:/etc $ ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:39:bb:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.X.13/24 brd 192.168.X.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 862050sec preferred_lft 754050sec
    inet 172.16.X.1/30 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 XXX:90X:XXX:5cXX:98e1:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 7046sec preferred_lft 3446sec
    inet6 XXX:90X:XXX:5cXX:ba27:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 6853sec preferred_lft 3253sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6c:ee:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The /64 scope IPv6 address with 'mngtmpaddr' corresponds to my MAC address. I assume that the IPv6 address before is a randomly generated address due to enabled IPv6 Privacy Extensions. In order for my new server to work, I just wanted to disable these Privacy Extensions.

According to this fairly recent [Explanation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111350/ipv6-privacy-extensions-sysctl-prefs-not-respected?newreg=1b59262aa72d494ab6131abc1a96408d) I need to change the settings in the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` from `slaac private` to `slaac hwaddr`. So I edited this file using  `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`, disabled private and enabled hwaddr. Then I checked, that the file was actually changed. Here is the file:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
##slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1
```

Unfortunately, after restart, I still get the above two IPv6 addresses!

I tried it several times, every time with a restart to see, if the settings stick. Unfortunately, it did not. So, I checked, if my Raspi was actually using DHCPCD by issuing `sudo service dhcpcd status`. If you look at the result, it seems to work fine:

```
pi@FIP-Box:/etc $ sudo service dhcpcd status
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-12 20:02:05 CET; 58min ago
 Main PID: 495 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 2059)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─436 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
           └─495 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

Jan 12 20:02:01 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: eth0: renew in 1800, rebind in 2880, expire in 7200 seconds
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: eth0: leased 192.168.X.13 for 864000 seconds
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.X.0/24
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.X.1
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: Too few arguments.
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: Too few arguments.
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box dhcpcd[370]: forked to background, child pid 495
Jan 12 20:02:05 XXX-Box systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Jan 12 20:02:45 XXX-Box dhcpcd[495]: eth0: fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX is reachable again
Jan 12 20:02:45 XXX-Box dhcpcd[495]: eth0: fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX is reachable again
```

Now I do not know what to do anymore. I suspect it is a dumb newbie error, but I have no clue.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken in the function of `slaac hwaddr`. This only affects the allocation of Stateless Address Autoconfiguration link addresses (and should be the default IMO).

The other addresses are allocated by DHCP; indeed you have 2 IPV4 & 2 IPV6 addresses. How or why has nothing to do with the Pi. You may have 2 DHCP servers.

Incidentally obscuring detail of private addresses is pointless and hiding DHCP assigned addresses just makes it harder for anyone to understand your network.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. It pointed me in the right direction.

I checked the settings of the DHCPv6 server in my router (a Fritz!Box 6660 Cable): It was set to assign both, the prefix (IA_PD) **and** the last part of the IPv6 address (IA_NA). I changed it to assign the prefix (IA_PD) only. After a restart of the Raspi he had one IPv6 address only - and this was the hardware address following my setting `slaac hwaddr`.